# Laravel auto generate migration scripts

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan, artisan-migrate

I am working on a php laravel webapp.

I am creating models for my database.

I have to write models class and migrations too.

Is there a way to only write model class and generate migration class automatically 
?

Artisan is not able to detect changes in Model class ?

Thanks

Comment: You can simply generate Model with using ```php artisan make:model YourModel -m```

Comment: Yes but it creates empty classes

Answer (score 0):

You can simply generate Model with using

```
php artisan make:model model-name -m
```

parameter -m stands for auto create migration while you are creating model.